# Simple Array not drawing class but printing it

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I am trying to figure out why is my Array not showing any lines, I am trying to make it draw 10 different lines, now println of x and z does show 10 coordinates but they are identical and it seems as if they are being passed down to the object line itself but not drawn. It seems quite simple but I know I've made a mistake somewhere but not sure where.

```
lines[] mylinesArray = new lines[10];


void setup() { 
  size(1028, 768, P3D);
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  rotateX(radians(180));
  float prp = -2000;
  float vrp = 50; 
  float z = random(prp, 2000);
  float x = random(vrp, 500);

  for (int i = 0; i<mylinesArray.length; i++) {
    mylinesArray[i] = new lines(z, 0, x);
    println(z);
    println(x);
  }
}



void draw() { 
  background(255);
  for (int i=0; i<mylinesArray.length; i++) {
   // println(i);
    mylinesArray[i].drawlines();

    //println("still doing it");
  }
}
class lines {

  color fillColor;
  color strokeColor;
  PVector dot1;
  PVector dot2;

  lines(float xpos, float ypos, float zpos) {
    dot1 = new PVector(500+xpos, 200, 700+zpos);
    dot2 = new PVector(500+xpos, -400, 700+zpos);
    fillColor = strokeColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }
  void drawlines() {
    pushMatrix();

    line (dot1.x, dot1.y, dot1.z, dot2.x, dot2.y, dot2.z);
    stroke(0);
   // println("new");
    popMatrix();
  }
  void whatever() {
 //   println("please");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are populating a 10 element `lines` array with identical coordinates in your `setup()` method (from within the for-loop). The z/x coordinates are then passed into `println()` 10 times. Perhaps you mean to put the `random()` method inside the for-loop?

Comment: @CPUTerminator Thank you that fixed it! Is there a reason why my line is not showing in the screen? I feel like I am so close to cracking these Arrays. Had been working on it the entire day.

Comment: I'm not sure what drawing framework you're using so I can't help in that aspect. I'd assumed the lines would start appearing once you've fixed the co-ordinates but if not, you need to provide more information about the drawing framework you are using. Also, remove irrelevant methods (e.g. `whatever()`).

Comment: @CPUTerminator will cleane it up, I am using Processing for this ,quite a beginner to be honest. Thank you again!